# GA Event Tracking or other tracking for open graph videos

Tags: facebook, video, google-analytics, jwplayer

I'm trying to find a good approach for tracking event data from videos that are played on Facebook. These are videos that are embedded into Facebook directly, where Facebook pulls in open graph meta data for the video.

I'm using JW Player, which has a google analytics plugin, but they've confirmed that it's not possible to use it while sharing on Facebook.

Would the Flash player itself theoretically be capable of sending event tracking data to Google if I hardcoded some modifications? I'm curious as to how the big players like YouTube and Vimeo provide analytical data for their videos that are shared with open graph tags.

I was thinking that maybe I could somehow use the Insights API with Facebook, which I'm looking into as well.

Thanks

**UPDATE** I've added a bounty to the post, and want the clarify a few things. JW Player developers have stated that their current Google Analytics plugin won't work because it's implemented using JavaScript and needs to be embedded with JW's embedder. Their earlier version of the plugin was implemented in Flash, but doesn't work *because facebook embeds the SWF's with the 'allowscriptaccess="never"' attribute*.

The allow script access restriction is disheartening, because from what I gather, that means that the embed src is restricted from making any HTTP requests (like to Google).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The allow script access restriction is disheartening, because from
>   what I gather, that means that the embed src is restricted from making
>   any HTTP requests (like to Google).

I think this is a misconception. The flash is still able to do HTTP requests from within the flash. The `allowscriptaccess="never` flag only disables flash from issuing javascript commands on the page and is nothing more than expected from facebook or any other network that allow users to post flash objects on other peoples timeline. If javascript access was allowed the flash object could inject malicious javascript scripts into facebook.

The recommended way to implement flash tracking for Google Analytics is to use the [gaforflash library](http://code.google.com/p/gaforflash/). This library has 2 modes, AS3 mode and BRIDGE mode. On BRIDGE mode the flash object issue javascript commands to the page, and on AS3 mode everything happens inside the flash.

For cases where you embed the player in a page you don't own you should use AS3 mode. So in this use case the correct would be to use AS3 mode.

Notice that JW Player has the Google Analytics PRO plugin. [Version 1](http://www.longtailvideo.com/AddOns/get-plugin.html?addon=107&vid=108) seems to support AS3 mode but [Version 2](http://www.longtailvideo.com/AddOns/get-plugin.html?addon=107&vid=292) doesn't have that option as far as I'm concerned. So you need to use Version 1 to be able to use AS3 mode.

Comment: Ah interesting. Thanks for the info! I've pinged long tail video about this. I assume they must implement version 1 of the plugin using BRIDGE mode, since they've told me that it relies on allowscriptaccess="always".

Comment: I would assume V2 uses BRIDGE mode hardcoded, because on V1 there's a setting where you can choose BRIDGE or AS3.

Comment: The indicate that V2 is a pure JS implementation, so none of it is in flash. They expose the player events to JS (both the HTML player and Flash player), and send the events to GA that way.

Answer (score -1):

Create an iFrame in FB and then you can track it however you please.

http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/tutorial-add-an-iframe-application-to-your-facebook-fan-page-fall-2012/

Another way:

http://www.facebook.com/iframe.apps

Once you have that you should have zero problem implementing any tracking you wish.  Personally if I were you I'd set up a subdomain specifically for pages viewed in that iFrame, for example: facevids.example.com and then use the profile filters to monitor that traffic.  Putting it in a subdomain and filtering it out of your main profile will prevent you from bloating your referral statistics from Facebook because every time that video pops up its going to tell you you're getting hits from FB.  More info on that here:

http://services.google.com/analytics/breeze/en/v5/filters_v15_ad1/

Here is a more in depth tutorial on how you can set this all up:

http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1972-how-to-track-across-multiple-subdomains-with-google-analytics/

This type of set up should give you the most accurate metrics.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. However, I'm talking about videos that are shared on Facebook on someone timeline, not videos that are embedded on an app. For example, when you copy and paste a youtube link and post it to your timeline, it embeds the YouTube player right in there. I can do the same, but I lose event tracking.

Comment: Ah yeah, ok that wasn't clear.  I would imagine you'd have to find a way to export the JW Player analytics over to Google post collection then.  You answered your own question, timelines on FB don't allow for external scripts to run and the Flash event tracking for GA requires that allowscriptaccess to be set to always.

Comment: I'm looking to see if anyone has any other options that I could use here then? I'm really curious how YouTube does it. I suppose they track that stuff server-side, but I think they would lose out on a lot of metrics that way.

Comment: Keep in mind that YouTube is owned by Google so transferring analytics into GA is a breeze for them.  You're trying to connect three completely separate entities that are in direct competition with each other and have various security measures to contend with.  I think you're trying to fit a square peg into a round hole here.